# Create Android Library Project Only

Tags: android, android-library

As much as I have researched, it seems that I am only able to create an `Android Library` *within* an Android Project. Is there any way in which I can create a Standalone Android Library and not have it within or alongside an App?

My scenario is to work on this Android Library and for it to create an `AAR` when I compile which I can then reference in a *separate* Android Project.

I so far have a project running but it has an App and a Library at the same level. I achieved this by creating a new project and then:

File -> New -> New Module -> Android Library.

Comment: The easiest way to do that is simply to remove the app module and delete its directory

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new Android Library, we'll call it "MyAar" (File -> New -> New Module -> Android Library)
2. Now there should be a folder named "MyAar" on the Android hierarchy (usually the left most window in Android Studio)
3. Add all the source code you want in there under the "Java" folder, and adjust your `build.gradle` file accordingly (the one that says "Modele:MyAar" and begins with `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`).
4. Highlight "MyAar" on the Android hierarchy window, then press <kbd>Build</kbd> -> <kbd>Make Module 'MyAar'</kbd> at the bar on the top (where File, Edit, View... is located)
5. Go to the folder `YOUR_ANDROID_APPLICATION/MyAar/build/outputs/aar`, you will see a `MyAar-debug.aar`. That is your .aar which you can now drop into any other project.